# git log --grep: search in the range from HEAD to the last (arbitrary) branch name

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I'm currently using Git as part of a tool in which I need to mark some Git repository changes. Therefore, I create some "marker commits". Now, I want to know how to efficiently find those commits.

The Git repositories all have a specific structure. I want to describe it on a concrete example:

Consider an arbitrary (big) repository with a detached HEAD that *always* has a linear chain up to an arbitrary next branch name. A `git log --oneline` on that repository would look like:

```
9b6eea6063ae (HEAD) foo
51206b9c09db bar
8ec634b9e864 baz
...
2fba8a89a6ee marker123
75a8e54af67e (some_branch) ipsum
...
```

I now want to find whether there exist a commit with the name `marker123` *on the path to the last branch*.

With `git log --grep marker123 --format=oneline --max-count=1 | grep .`, I found a command that searches for that name and returns no error, when the commit exists and an error, when it not exists. However, if no commit `marker123` exists, it searches *the whole history*. Can I restrict the search of `git log` to the range between `HEAD` and `some_branch`? My main problem is that I do not know the name of `some_branch` in advance. I only know that it is somewhere on the linear chain of back commits and is a branch name.
Especially, I do not know how to define a commit range for `git log`.

Side note: I know this behavior a little bit from `git rebase -i` without an additional specification of the target commit. It also does a rebase starting from the last (remote?) branch then.

Here is a script to setup two repositories and demonstrate the problem:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo "Setup a repository, where the search works."
mkdir git-test; cd git-test
git init --initial-branch=random_name
git commit --allow-empty -m "marker123"
git tag "This-commit-never-ever-should-be-found"
git commit --allow-empty -m "ipsum"
git checkout --detach HEAD
git commit --allow-empty -m "marker123"
git commit --allow-empty -m "baz"
git commit --allow-empty -m "bar"
git commit --allow-empty -m "foo"

git log --oneline # situation of the example
echo -e "\nSearch for marker:"
git log --grep "marker123" --oneline -1 | grep .
echo "Errorcode $?"

cd ..

echo "Setup a repository, where the search does not work."
mkdir git-test2; cd git-test2
git init --initial-branch=random_name
git commit --allow-empty -m "marker123"
git tag "This-commit-never-ever-should-be-found"
git commit --allow-empty -m "ipsum"
git checkout --detach HEAD
# git commit --allow-empty -m "marker123" # this commit is missing here
git commit --allow-empty -m "baz"
git commit --allow-empty -m "bar"
git commit --allow-empty -m "foo"

git log --oneline # situation of the example
echo -e "\nSearch for marker:"
git log --grep "marker123" --oneline -1 | grep . # this should result in an error
echo "Errorcode $?"
git log --grep "marker123" --oneline -1 "random_name..HEAD" | grep . # this works here but only if random_name is known
echo "Errorcode $?"

cd ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can :

- list the branches that do not contain `HEAD`:

```
git branch --no-contains HEAD
```

- use that list in a `git log HEAD --not [list of branches ...]` command:

```
git log --oneline HEAD --not $(git branch --no-contains HEAD)
```

---

If the above command gives you the history you expect, you can add whatever options you see fit to git log:

```
git log --grep marker123 -1 --oneline HEAD --not $(git branch --no-contains HEAD)
```

Comment: That works in principal. Thank you! Since my branches are remote branches, I modfied your command a little bit: `git log --grep marker123 -1 --oneline HEAD --not $(git branch -a --no-contains=HEAD --format="%(objectname)")`

Comment: If you want to check commits that aren't pushed, you can try `--not --remotes`